# AWS Sns publish stops the execution after sending the push notification (publish) in PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm trying to send AWS push notification (SNS) to multiple devices one by one. 
When I check the response of Publish, they are actually getting send. 
I have created different function for sending the SNS and calling it from another function.

But after calling the `Publish` method the execution gets stop. The next statement after the called function does not get execute.
I'm not able to find reason for this.